# Sharepoint Online: StartUpload API throwing error while uploading content for OneNote

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business, onenote

I've been using the following endpoint ([StartUpload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileStartUpload)) for uploading content to OneNote items on my OneDrive

> https://tenantName-my.sharepoint.com/personal/some-user_some_domain/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl(@v)/startupload(uploadId=guid'2102fa7c-28d6-11e7-ab31-06a6507649eb')?@v='/personal/some-user_some_domain/Documents/Notebooks/Abc/My.one'

For the past 1 week I am noticing the following exception (intermittent)

> {"error":{"code":"-1, Cobalt.ErrorExceptionTag","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Error=Value=FdaSchemaInvalid, Tag=0x0121d2cf"}}}

For another tenant I see it works sometimes, but for others I happen to get this exception quite alot.

Has anything changed recently?